# Can not print PDF insert into HTML

Tags: html, pdf

I have an html document and i inserted a pdf file with:

```
<iframe id="fred" style="border:1px solid #666CCC" title="PDF in an i-Frame" src="C:test.pdf" frameborder="1" scrolling="auto" height="100%" width="100%" ></iframe>
```

I can visualize my document and the pdf, but when i try to print it or send it by email, the pdf is not there anymore.

How can I make for don't lose the pdf file in any action I do with the document or if i want to open the file in a different server or different computer?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it with Google Drive:
Go to [drive.google.com](http://drive.google.com)
Upload the file
Embed it on your website